# is there any way to have redux-form ignore dots in a field name?

Tags: redux-form

i have a restful api that accepts dotted(path) strings as parameter keys.

for example, i can call this:

```
/widgets?material.type=iron
```

so i have a redux-form field like:

```
<Field name="material.type" component={TextField} label="material type" />
```

but redux-form interprets the dot in `material.type` and when passed to my handler ends up as `{material: {type: 'iron'}}`.

i understand why this is the default behavior, but i was wondering if there is an easy way to thwart it with a property or something such that i can get `{'material.type': 'iron'}` instead?

Comment: did you find a way to get over this issue?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. Redux Form will always nest field values under objects when their name contain a dot - internally [`_.toPath`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPath) is used, and it doesn't have a way to escape characters.

What you could do instead is to rename the value when assigning `initialValues`:

```
initialValues: {
  ...formData,
  materialType: formData['material.type']
}
```

...and when submitting the form:

```
onSubmit (values) {
  return submitSomehow({
    ...values,
    'material.type': values.materialType
  })
}
```